# Font family resource from theme not applied to TextViews

Tags: android, textview, android-resources, android-fonts

I want to set the `android:textAppearance` of several `TextViews`. To do that, I have declared the following style:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textFontWeight">400</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_215</item>
</style>
```

Said style will be set to the `attr` of `textAppearanceHeadline` in my theme like so:

```
<item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline1</item>
```

The font family XML is written like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="200"
        app:font="@font/montserrat_extralight" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/montserrat_regular" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="500"
        app:font="@font/montserrat_medium" />

    <font
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="600"
        app:font="@font/montserrat_semibold" />
</font-family>
```

All the `@font/montserrat_*` references are `.ttf` files that I've included in my resources folder. Then, I will set the style using said `attr` value to the `TextView` I want to style like so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Writing Words"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/headingView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/headingView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headingView" />
```

The problem is, the font family and font-weight are applied incorrectly (they change to the default font family and font-weight). The size is applied correctly. Did I do something wrong here?

**UPDATE**

When I try setting only either `android:textAppearance` or `style` to the `TextView` with `?attr/textAppearanceHeadline1`, it doesn't set the font-family and font-weight. However, when I set `android:fontFamily` and `android:fontWeight` alongside `android:textAppearance`, it works. Setting those alongside `style` does not work. Why is that so? What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I have to override `fontFamily` also. Overriding `fontFamily` in my style makes it work flawlessly. The style becomes the following.

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textFontWeight">400</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_215</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Because of things like that I really, really hate the Android View styling system!

Answer (score -1):

Probably in your xml exist viewGroup (where your's TextView one of the child) with style that have `android:fontFamily` that override your's `android:textAppearance`

Comment: I've checked, there isn't.